# How to get the number of equal matches per column in a two dimensional array?

Tags: java

I have an array called correctAnswer which have 10 values. every value is either A, B, C or D.

Then I have a Two-dimensional array called studentAnswers which have 3 rows and 10 columns. 
I want to make a method which check how many matches there are for each column.

For example:

Correct answers:  [B, C, A, A, B, A, C, D, A, C]

Student 1 result: C, D, C, D, B, D, C, C, A, B
Student 2 result: A, A, B, C, D, C, B, B, D, D
Student 3 result: A, C, C, C, B, C, A, A, A, A

Then it should print:

Answer 1: 0
Answer 2: 1
and so on... until it reach 10 because there is 10 values in the array correctAnswers

Here is my code so far:

```
private char[] correctAnswer = { 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C' };

private char[][] studentAnswers;

// constructor
    public MultipleChoice(int numberOfStudents) {
    studentAnswers = new char[numberOfStudents][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < studentAnswers[i].length; j++) {
            int tal = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
            char c = (char) (tal + 'A');
            studentAnswers[i][j] = c;
        }
    }
}

// my method
public void printCorrectAnswerPrQuestion() {
    for (int i = 0; i < correctAnswer.length; i++) {

        System.out.print("number of correct answers to question number " + correctAnswer[i + 1] + ": ");
        int correctAnswers= 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < correctAnswer.length; j++) {
            if (correctAnswer[j] == studentAnswers[i][j]) {
                correctAnswers= correctAnswers+ 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(correctAnswers);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Describe what is not working

Comment: I want to check how many matches there are for each column from the array correctAnswers

Comment: And what do you mean by matches? Please edit the question with a sample input

Comment: The array correctAnswers starts with the value B. if any of the columns in the two dimensional array studentAnswers starts with the value B then there is a match. Then i want to count the number of matches for each value in the array correctAnswers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong condition on the outer for loop `i < correctAnswer.length`. It must be `studentAnswers.length`. This will give the number of correct answers for each student.

---

If you want to know the number of students who have correctly answered a question

```
for (int i = 0; i < correctAnswer.length; i++) {
    int correctAnswers = 0;
    System.out.print("number of correct answers to question number " + i + ": ");

    for (int j = 0; j < studentAnswers.length; j++) {
        if (correctAnswer[i] == studentAnswers[j][i]) {
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(correctAnswers);
}
```

Comment: @user3740970 See my updated answer. The first will get the number of correct answers for a student. The second will get the number of students with right answers for a question.